# A parbox inside a textblock

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, margins, textpos, parbox

I would like to have **absolute positioning** with centering **vertical alignment**. I am trying to achieve this by using a `\parbox` inside a `\textblock` (from `textpos`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay,showboxes]{textpos}
\begin{document}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \begin{textblock*}{1in}(1in,1in)\noindent
        \fbox{\parbox[c][1in][c]{1in}{Hallo}}
    \end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```

However, it the widths of the `textblock` and the `parbox` do not match. Does anybody know where this unwanted extra spacing comes from and how to remove it?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a word space after the fbox, which I comment out here, and you need to allow for the width of the fbox rules

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay,showboxes]{textpos}
\begin{document}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \begin{textblock*}{1in}(1in,1in)\noindent
        \fbox{\parbox[c][\dimexpr 1in-2\fboxrule][c]{\dimexpr 1in-2\fboxrule}{Hallo}}%
    \end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```